# aggregate of an empty result set

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregate-functions

I would like the aggregates of an empty result set to be 0. I have tried the following:

```
SELECT SUM(COALESCE(capacity, 0))
  FROM objects
 WHERE null IS NOT NULL;
```

Result:

```
sum 
-----

(1 row)
```

Subquestion: wouldn't the above work in Oracle, using `SUM(NVL(capacity, 0))`?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

From [the documentation page](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/static/functions-aggregate.html) about aggregate functions:

> It should be noted that except for `count`, these functions **return a null value when no rows are selected**. In particular, `sum` of no rows returns null, not zero as one might expect. The `coalesce` function may be used to substitute zero for null when necessary.

So, if you want to guarantee a value returned, apply `COALESCE` to the *result* of `SUM`, not to its argument:

```
SELECT COALESCE(SUM(capacity), 0) …
```

As for the Oracle 'subquestion', well, I couldn't find any notion of NULLs at the official doc page ([the one for 10.2](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions163.htm), in particular), but two other sources are unambiguous:

- [Oracle SQL Functions](http://ss64.com/ora/syntax-functions.html):

  > `SUM([DISTINCT] n)` Sum of values of n, *ignoring NULLs*
- [sum aggregate function [Oracle SQL]](http://www.adp-gmbh.ch/ora/sql/agg/sum.html):

  > …if a sum() is created over some numbers, *nulls are disregarded*, as the following example shows…

That is, you needn't apply NVL to `capacity`. (But, like with `COALESCE` in PostgreSQL, you might want to apply it to `SUM`.)

Comment: Shouldn't it be `to substitute null for zero` instead of quoted `to substitute zero for null`? I am not native speaker though.

Comment: @VlastimilOvčáčík: Neither am I. Hopefully whoever wrote that passage in the docs was! :) Seriously, though, that phrase is correct English. "Substitute A for B" means the same as "replace *or* substitute B with A". English grammar – go figure!

Comment: You're [right](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/23360/substitute-x-for-y)! But it is tricky one.

Answer (score 6):

The thing is, the aggregate always returns a row, even if no rows were aggregated (as is the case in your query). You summed an expression over no rows. Hence the null value you're getting.

Try this instead:

```
select coalesce(sum(capacity),0)
from objects
where false;
```

Comment: you can simplify that with coalesce(sum(capacity),0) since sum() will ignore NULL values.

Comment: @peufeu: true, but if his actual query uses a left join, null + anything yields null, as does sum with a potentially null field.

Comment: peufeu is right. The coalesce inside your SUM is redundant. See my answer's code simulation

Comment: Yup. I still get mixed up on this here and there. Trauma from having debugged something to the order of `sum(round(stuff))` in pg8. :-)

Comment: sum() of a nullable field returns the sum of the non-null values. sum() is not the same as what you'd get by adding all the values including null...

Answer (score 1):

Just do this:

```
SELECT COALESCE( SUM(capacity), 0)
FROM objects
WHERE null IS NOT NULL;
```

By the way, COALESCE inside of SUM is redundant, even if capacity is NULL, it won't make the summary null.

To wit:

```
create table objects
(
    capacity int null
);

insert into objects(capacity) values (1),(2),(NULL),(3);

select sum(capacity) from objects;
```

That will return a value of 6, not null.

And a coalesce inside an aggregate function is a performance killer too, as your RDBMS engine cannot just *rip through* all the rows, it has to evaluate each row's column if its value is null. I've seen a bit OCD query where all the aggregate queries has a coalesce inside, I think the original dev has a symptom of [Cargo Cult Programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_programming), the query is way very sloooowww. I removed the coalesce inside of SUM, then the query become fast.

Answer (score 0):

Although this post is very old, but i would like to update what I use in such cases

```
SELECT NVL(SUM(NVL(capacity, 0)),0)
FROM objects
WHERE false;
```

Here external NVL avoids the cases when there is no row in the result set. Inner NVL is used for null column values, consider the case of (1 + null) and it will result in null. So inner NVL is also necessary other wise in alternate set default value 0 to the column.

Comment: The `SUM` function ignores `NULL` values, so the inner `NVL` function (or `COALESCE`, or `ISNULL` in other dialects) is redundant. Only the outer one is necessary.